# Loading string from json file

Tags: python, json, string

I am using the following code to load a list of words from a json file:

```
import json
with open('important_words.json', 'r') as f:
    important_words = json.load(f)
```

Inspecting the variable important_words:

```
type(important_words)
=> list
important_words
=>
[u'use',
 u'one',
 u'great',
```

I assumed the content of the list would be string, but it seems I need to do the following (explicitly convert the content of list to string):

```
important_words = [str(s) for s in important_words]
type(important_words)
=> list
important_words
=>
['use',
 'one',
 'great',
```

Two questions:
- Why `json.load()` create a list of strings?
- I understand 'use' is a string, but is the significance of `u'use'` (the u before the 'use').

Comment: What's in your JSON file? It sounds like it's valid JSON in a list representation, which is why you get a list back.

Comment: The `u` prefix is just to say that they are _unicode_. Other than that, it's not clear to me why you'd expect `json.load()` to return a string representation of your entire list (IIUC), since that's not a lot of use.